# Why this errror appears during fit while creating decision Tree Classifier

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

Hi I am trying Decision Tree Classifier by following this video Hello World - Machine Learning Recipes #1 Google Developers.

Here is my Code.

```
#Import the Pandas library
  import pandas as pd
#Load the train and test datasets to create two DataFrames
train_url = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/course/Kaggle/train.csv" train = pd.read_csv(train_url)
#Print the head of the train and test dataframes
train.head() 
test_url = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/course/Kaggle/test.csv" test = pd.read_csv(test_url)
#Print the head of the train and test dataframes
test.head()
#from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import tree
#find the best feature to predict Survival rate
#define X_features and Y_labels
col_names=['Pclass','Age','SibSp','Parch']
X_features= train[col_names]
#assign survial to label
Y_labels= train.Survived
#create a decision tree classifier
clf=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
#fit (find patterns in Data)
clf=clf.fit(X_features, Y_labels)
clf.predict(test[col_names])
```

## Getting Error

> ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) in () 13#Y_train_sparse=Y_labels.to_sparse() 14 # fit (find patterns in Data) ---> 15 clf=clf.fit(X_features, Y_labels) 16 #clf.predict(test[col_names])
>
> C:\Users\nitinahu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py
>   in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted) 152
>   random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state) 153 if
>   check_input: --> 154 X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE,
>   accept_sparse="csc") 155 if issparse(X): 156 X.sort_indices()
>
> C:\Users\nitinahu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py
>   in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy,
>   force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
>   ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator) 396 % (array.ndim,
>   estimator_name)) 397 if force_all_finite: --> 398
>   _assert_all_finite(array) 399 400 shape_repr = _shape_repr(array.shape)
>
> C:\Users\nitinahu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py
>   in _assert_all_finite(X) 52 and not np.isfinite(X).all()): 53 raise
>   ValueError("Input contains NaN, infinity" ---> 54 " or a value too
>   large for %r." % X.dtype) 55 56
>
> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float32').

Comment: Hello, you should refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help you get started.  In general, a question is not well received when the poster post code and asks why it doesn't work.  It shows very little effort on your part.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Isn't it `valueError`, may be some value is out of limits allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Just check all the values u r getting in the responses.

One or two is giving out of bound values and that is causing an overflow to occur.

Comment: I checked that there are NaN in 'Age' column, how to find NaN in 'Age' column in train and test data set and replace with some real value